# Xamarin Android App causes device reboot

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I didn't change anything in my app, except of icon, and now it reboots the whole system, can't try to catch logs, cause they clears after lost connection, app can't even start it reboots immediately after I click on my app icon, what may be the reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I didn't noticed, that icon of my app is too large, 4986x4986, so I just resized it to smaller size and everything is ok now