# Splash Screen Activity forces my device to restart

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-appcompat, splash-screen

I am viewing an article on *Xamarin* that guides how we can add a Splash Screen on an *AppCompatActivity*. Whenever I run the application it forces my device to restart.

Here is what I have done to get the issue solved and I was failed.

1. Setting the Java max heap size to 1G
2. Properly followed the steps listed on [Xamarin article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/) for splash screen creation
3. Properly installed AppCompatv7 and v4 support

Still the issue is there.
**Here is my code for it** maybe I am doing something wrong in the coding part.

**Splash Activity**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TestApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "SplashActivity", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash")]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            var startupTask = new Task(SimulateStartup);
            startupTask.Start();

        }
        private async void SimulateStartup()
        {
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using System;
using Android.Content;

namespace TestApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "MainActivity")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }


    }
}
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">

  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash" android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="center" /> 
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#4682b4</color>
  <color name="primaryDark">#2c6493</color>
  <color name="accent">#FFC107</color>
  <color name="window_background">#F5F5F5</color>
  <color name="splash_background">#4682b4</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your bitmap size. If it is too big it may cause a reboot: see [Xamarin Android App causes device reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420025/xamarin-android-app-causes-device-reboot)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my pictures size in kilobytes was 331KB but it's resoultion was 4488x5315.